# Sending and receiving different types of messages with spray

Tags: scala, spray

I am using spray routing and spray client.
I see that pipleline in spray client allows to define, by default, one and only one type of answer.
I want to expose with spray routing a rest json service which replies either with a ServiceResponse type, either with a Error response type.
I can define types and marshalling of ServiceResponse and Error on spray routing, and define a route which returns either a ServiceResponse or an Error.

I don't see how to call that from spray client, since the result would be a Future[ServiceResponse] or Future[Error].
The only solution I made work is to define an encapsulation : MetaResponse(Option(ServiceResponse), Option[Error]). 
In the spray client I use pattern matching to know in which case I am.  But I find this solution ugly.

Is there a way to specify that a given client request can expect several return types?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `Either[ServiceResponse, Error]`? Also.you might want to change the HTTP Status code, 200 for `ServiceResponse` and something in the 4xx or 5xx range for `Error`

Comment: Hello, no I haven't tried.  Actually my main concern is, I don't find that much documentation on the web.  But I am going to try today, thanks.  For the error, I want to send also a specific message along with the code.  Thanks.